# Would PHP ever work in Chrome but NOT Safari?

Tags: php, google-chrome, safari

Is there any reason why PHP would work in Chrome, but not in Safari?

I'm just doing a simple if statement, which is correct and thus echos out an element in Chrome, but in Safari, it doesn't.

```
<?php if (($layout->article_overview_flexible_layout_type->id === 1 || $layout->article_overview_flexible_layout_type->id === 2) && ($layout->next->article_overview_flexible_layout_type->id === 3 || $layout->next->article_overview_flexible_layout_type->id === 4)) : ?>
    <div class="article-overview-layout-sep"></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

See screenshot. Left is Chrome, right is Safari. I didn't think this was ever possible because it's server side? I'm guessing I am missing something? I'll go through all my code for this template.

[image: Source]

[image: Inspect]

Comment: Unlikely, unless the server side code relies on cookies or other data sent from the browser. 1st step is to view source, not inspect element.

Comment: View source will show the raw html, inspect elelement shows the browser generated DOM. Often the browser will try to correct broken html, and some are better at it than others

Comment: @Steve Thanks. Having a look now.

Comment: @Steve No unclosed tags. Even ran a checker.

Comment: Does the source appear the same in both browsers? If yes, as i guess, then its a html/css issue, which should be a separate SO question. If it is indeed different, then its some weird cookie/header issue, which can only be tracked down by viewing the request details in the networking tab

Comment: @Steve I just ran a checker on the source... exactly the same. I just can't understand why the PHP wouldn't work as I can clearly see, even in the source, that the statement is true.

Comment: if the html source in both browsers is the same, then it has nothing to do with php - the if statement is working as expected and outputting `<div class="article-overview-layout-sep"></div>` in both cases. Its an html/css issue

Comment: Oh sorry! No, I meant the HTML source is exactly the same except that `sep` div. Added new screenshot as proof.

Comment: Weird, well its back to checking headers etc. Are you logged in with one browser and not the other? If you dont have a debugger set up, a start would be to put `<!--<?php var_dump(get_defined_vars()));?>-->` at the bottom of your script/view file and see whats different in the two browsers source

Comment: @JohnthePainter please post code and not pictures of code! This is frowned upon on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Steve I set up some PHP debug. In Safari I get this Notice 'Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Sites/yas/site/templates/article-overview.php on line 130' whereas on Chrome I don't get any notice. This line, 130, is my if statement included above.

Comment: ugh, sounds like Drupal. I would assume the ->next just isn't set for one browser (cookies?) but for the other it is? (perhaps the next item is actually not visible for the user that is logged in with the first)

Comment: @Jakumi It's actually ProcessWire but that IS EXACTLY WHAT IT WAS. The field I was querying is only accessible when logged in. And Safari wasn't logged in.

Comment: added it as an answer for the generations to come.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field you're accessing is likely accessible with chrome but not with safari, due to different parameters on some level, like:

- **logged in as a different user or not logged in at all on one browser** (that's the one in this case)
- different (query) parameters in url
- different parameters in cookie
- in case that gets tested: different user-agent or anything else that the browser sends to the server to "improve user experience" (prefered language, ...)